# reclyclerview disappears while switching fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout

I'm have a Bottom Navigation View with 3 options and fragments.

when I go to the fragment that has a tabLayout with a recycler view inside, the first time the list is loaded correctly, however after changing the fragment and returning to the list, the list is not shown.

The code:

 Fragment of RecyclerView.

```
public class CadastroContaPatrimonialFragment extends Fragment {

@BindView(R.id.recyclerView_conta_patrimonial)
public RecyclerView recyclerViewContaPatrimonial;

private CadastroContaPatrimonialAdapter adapter;
private List<ContaPatrimonial> listaContas;


public static CadastroContaPatrimonialFragment newInstance() {
    CadastroContaPatrimonialFragment fragment = new CadastroContaPatrimonialFragment();
    return fragment;
}

public CadastroContaPatrimonialFragment() {}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cadastro_conta_patrimonial, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    if (this.listaContas == null) {
        configuraRecycler();
    }

    return view;
}

private void configuraRecycler() {

    MainActivity.loading(true);

    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerViewContaPatrimonial.setLayoutManager(manager);

    ContaPatrimonialDAO contaPatrimonialDAO = PatrimonioDatabase.getInstance(getContext()).criaContaPatrimonialDAO();
    this.listaContas = contaPatrimonialDAO.getAll();
    adapter = new CadastroContaPatrimonialAdapter(this.listaContas);

    recyclerViewContaPatrimonial.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerViewContaPatrimonial.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

    MainActivity.loading(false);
}
```

}

Adapter:

```
public class CadastroContaPatrimonialAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CadastroContaPatrimonialAdapter.ContaPatrimonialViewHolder> {

List<ContaPatrimonial> contas;

public CadastroContaPatrimonialAdapter(List<ContaPatrimonial> contas) {
    this.contas = contas;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ContaPatrimonialViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ContaPatrimonialViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
           .inflate(R.layout.conta_patrimonial_item_recycler, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ContaPatrimonialViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.txtContaDescricao.setText(contas.get(position).getDescricao());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return contas != null ? contas.size() : 0;
}

/* VIEW HOLDER */
public class ContaPatrimonialViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.item_conta_patr_descricao)
    public TextView txtContaDescricao;

    public ContaPatrimonialViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}
```

}

Switch fragments:

```
private void trocaFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean backStack) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction tx = fm.beginTransaction();
    tx.replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment);
    if (backStack) {
        tx.addToBackStack(null);
    }
    tx.commit();
}
```

Comment: Override `onResume()` method of fragment and call `configuraRecycler()` from that method.

Comment: I already tried it and it did not work. I put a logd in onResume () but it seems that when returning to this fragment, it is not going through this function

Comment: One important information is that this tablayout is within a fragment, which is within another fragment.
Example: I have the bottomNavView, and each option is a fragment, in this fragment there is another fragment containing the recycler view.

Answer (score 0):

Your `RecyclerView` does not disappear when the fragment switches back, it just doesn't render correctly as expected. When a fragment switches back from `FragmentTransaction.replace`, it calls `Fragment.onCreateView` again because the view was destroyed. And in your case, you skip configuring the `RecyclerView` because `listaContas` was initialised previously. To fix it, you should remove `if (this.listaContas == null)` condition:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cadastro_conta_patrimonial, container, false);
}

@Override public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    configuraRecycler();
}
```

Comment: Not worked for me. I put a logd in this method and it's like it did not pass through it